# How is the range of long double in C calculated?

Tags: c

While studying C I came to know that range of long double is 3.4E-4932 to 1.1E+4932. What is E here ? Size of long double in 10 bytes. If I assume E is 10 then how long double stores numbers till 19 places after decimal.

Comment: Yes E denotes a decimal power, the usual scientific notation. The rest of your question makes no sense.

Comment: You might find [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) instructive.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format

Answer (score 2):

3.4E-4932 means [image].  Both floats and doubles are stored in a format that keeps the exponent and the mantissa separate.  In your example, -4392 will be encoded in the exponent, and 3.4 will be encoded in the mantissa, both as binary numbers.

Note that IEEE floating point formats come in a variety of ranges with availability that varies by platform.  Refer to [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for more details.  As pointed out by Joe Farrell, your range is probably [x86 Extended Precision Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format).  That format carries 1 bit for sign (s), 15 bits of binary exponent (e) with a bias of -16383, and 1 + 63 bits of binary mantissa (m).  For normalized numbers, the value is computed as [image].

The smallest positive normalized number in this format has a sign bit of 0, an exponent of 1, and a mantissa of 1.0, corresponding to [image] or [image].  In binary, that number looks like:

[image]

Comment: Given the range specified in the OP, it's probably [this format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) instead. It's probably also worth noting that, as far as I know, C doesn't give the exact specification to be used for `long double`, so different implementations of C may use different representations with different limits.

Comment: Only in the rare 10-base floating point formats. Usually it is a 2-base, where your numbers are incorrect. The range in 10-base only approximates the typical format, and certainly -4392 will not be encoded in the exponent, or 3.4 in the mantissa, since the mantissa is of the range `1.0 ... 1.999999~` (decimal) or `1.0 ... 1.111111~` (binary).

Comment: @JoeFarrell  I think you're right.  Feel free to edit.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Agreed that neither -4932 nor 3.4 would show up as directly at the bit level.  When I mentioned where each part was encoded, I meant to convey to the OP that the exponent and mantissa (and hence the range and precision) were independent of each other.  I also find it interesting that this particular format seems to have an explicit rather than implicit 1 for the integer part of the mantissa.

Comment: With the IEEE format the m.s. `1` of the mantissa is implicit. A 32-bit float has a 24-bit mantissa, only 23 of which are encoded.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I agree with you about the 1 being implicit for IEEE single and double precision formats, but for the [x86 extended precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) I find:  "In contrast to the single and double-precision formats, this format does not utilize an implicit/hidden bit. Rather, bit 63 contains the integer part of the significand and bits 62-0 hold the fractional part. Bit 63 will be 1 on all normalized numbers. There were several advantages to this design when the 8087 was being developed."

Answer (score 0):

The range of a long double (or, indeed, any floating point width) on Intel hardware is typically `[-∞, ∞]`. Between those endpoints many finite numbers are also representable:

- 0
- ±m×2<sup>e</sup>, where:
- m is an integer between 1 and 2<sup>64</sup>-1, and
- e is an integer between -16445 and 16320

That means that the smallest non-zero long double is 2<sup>-16445</sup> and the largest finite long double is (2<sup>64</sup>-1)·2<sup>16320</sup> (or 2<sup>16384</sup>-2<sup>16320</sup>), which are *approximately* equal to the decimal numbers in scientific notation in the question.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) for details on the representation (which is binary, not decimal).